# preg_match_all vs. explode

Tags: php, explode, preg-match-all

why don't the following two php-codes return the same?

Code 1:

```
$words = "music band sound";
preg_match_all("/\w+/", strtoupper($words), $matches);
$words = $matches[0];
```

and Code 2:

```
$words = "music band sound";
$woerter  = strtoupper($words);
$teile = explode(" ", $woerter);
$words = $teile[0];
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to test it altleast? by echoing it you'll simply know what was happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$teile` is the array of words in your second example, and `$words = $teile[0];` simply gets the first entry/word from that array. Whereas `$words` in your first example is the full array.

Answer (score 0):

Why the `$teile[0]`? You want `$teile`.

Answer (score 0):

Preg_match_all returns an array of arrays.  Matches[0] contains all patterns matched by /w+/.  You could use matches[0][0] to grab "music".

So matches[0] in the firat example is the equivilant of tiele in the second.

https://www.php.net/preg_match_all